# How Can I initialize multiple wysihtml5 editor on same page?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysihtml5

When I initialize bootstrap-wysihtml5 with class name it will only initialize first one and rest of the remain normal text-area

Is there any way to handle it

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.vid_description').wysihtml5();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the method wysihtml5() is only called for the first element.

Iterate over all elements and call the initialization method for each element separately:

```
$('.vid_description').each(function() {
    $(this).wysihtml5();
});
```